# For which $c\in \mathbb R$ the function $\kappa(t) := ct^4(1-t)^4$ can be curvature of regular, closed, convex curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, convex-geometry

I have the following problem.
Suppose $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ is regular, closed and convex curve.
For which $c\in \mathbb R$ can the following function:
$\kappa:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ ; $\kappa(t)= ct^4(1-t)^4$  can be it's curvature (meaning signed curvature , because curvature is always positive by definition)?

My (attempt of) solution:

1. Because $\alpha$ is convex we know that $\alpha\prime\prime\geq0$ $ \forall t\in[0,1]$
2. Because $\alpha$ is closed then there exists $T>0$ such that $\alpha(t) = \alpha(t+T)$ $ \forall t\in[0,1]$.
3. $c\neq0$ because otherwise we have that $\kappa=0$ therefore, $\alpha$ is part of straight line and can't be closed. contradiction.
4. I've read that convex curves curvature is $\geq0$ but I can't find a proper proof for this.

Therefore, in conclusion I get that for any $c>0$ $\kappa(t)$ can be it's curvature.
Did I'm miss something?

Comment: The curvature is the reciprocal of the radius of curvature.  If c is small, $\alpha([0,1])$ will be an almost straight line segment.  If c is large, the path will wrap around several times, crossing itself.  You need to find the c for which the path does one loop and ends up at its starting point.

Comment: Thanks! So this is actually the same thing as finding $c>0$ such that the integral on this segment of $\kappa$ is equal $2\pi$ i.e. total curvature is $2\pi$?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So I've managed to combine a formal answer for this question.
$\gamma$ is convex i.e. simple curve by definition therefore, by Hopf Umlaufsatz theorem taking in account that $\gamma$ is simple and closed we get that the value of $\int_\gamma \kappa(t) dt = +/- 2\pi$.
Therefore by simple computation (and taking in account that $\kappa > 0$ because it is convex) we get that $c=1260\pi$